# Magento - Make side navigation links be SEO Friendly

Tags: url, magento

My top category links are linking properly,

Dining Room: www.yoursite.com/dining-room-furniture.html

But My Subcategories are linking like this
Dining Room Chairs: www.yoursite.com/dining-room-furniture.html?cat=87

instead of this
Dining Room Chairs: www.yoursite.com/dining-room-furniture/chairs.html

is there a way to have them link the way that I set it up in Admin/Catalog/Manage Categories? So that I can potentially get Ranking for dining room furniture chairs instead of cat 87.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Magento Subcategories in Side Layered Navigation to Point to Actual Categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061575/change-magento-subcategories-in-side-layered-navigation-to-point-to-actual-categ)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin for this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seo-layered-navigation-6466.html

Comment: thank you for the quick response!  so is there not a way to change the code or something in the back end to fix this?

Comment: Yes you can create your own module to achieve this if you can’t or don’t want to pay for the Ecommerce Team module. But my guess is it will take you a lot more than $100 worth of your time to do it. If you still want to do it yourself then you need to start looking at how to create a module and take it from there (and that itself is not a quick or easy thing for a beginner to achieve) (I’m guessing you’re a Magento beginner due to the nature of your question – if I’m wrong I apologise). For some good tutorials to get you started have a look at Alan Storm: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento.